# Mapbox tiles and Leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to load some additional tile layers on my map but I can't quite figure it out.  The ones that I currently have I only have thanks to someone that provided a tutorial but didn't say what the other tile options were.  Can someone help me with this?

```
var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}';
var accessToken = 'mySuperSecretToken';

var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: '', maxZoom: 20, accessToken: accessToken}),
streets = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets', attribution: '', maxZoom: 20, accessToken: accessToken});
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get any additional layers or even use the new streets version that I got an email about today.

Answer (score 53):

I actually finally found the answer.

The URL string needed to be updated to

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}
```

The available styles ({id}) are

- streets-v9
- satellite-streets-v9
- light-v9
- dark-v9
- outdoors-v9

Comment: The latest list is here: https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#styles

Comment: You saved my life

Answer (score 17):

Full list of Mapbox classic map IDs, ie for Leaflet, are at https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps.

At the time of writing the IDs are:

- mapbox.streets
- mapbox.light
- mapbox.dark
- mapbox.satellite
- mapbox.streets-satellite
- mapbox.wheatpaste
- mapbox.streets-basic
- mapbox.comic
- mapbox.outdoors
- mapbox.run-bike-hike
- mapbox.pencil
- mapbox.pirates
- mapbox.emerald
- mapbox.high-contrast

Comment: is there a way to make the id dynamic, for example switching between mapbox.satellite and mapbox,streets when clicking a button or something ?

Comment: I can't seem to find the IDs anymore on the mapbox docs, not even at the link @VictorHäggqvist provided. Is it just me or did they actually hide them somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the new tile layers 'styles' that Mapbox was referring to were *vector tile layers*.

**Mapbox-GL JS** uses vector [styles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles) which you listed (xxx-v9). (up to date as of 05/2019)

**Mapbox JS** is built on top of Leaflet  `(L.tilelayer())` and uses raster tilesets, which are images.  [Here are the available basemaps](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps) from Mapbox.

Comment: I can not find the MapBox JS build basemaps on that link. Did they change the link?

Comment: The links have changed, mapbox no longer maintains this api and it seems they have gone out of their way to hide this information. The answer above from Victor has a pretty good, probably comprehensive list of available basemaps.