# Mapbox styles similar to google maps using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I found in this thread available styles for leaflet: [Mapbox tiles and Leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166172/mapbox-tiles-and-leafletjs)

But I am looking for something more similar to google maps.

On the website of MapBox there is a gallery with this style: 
https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/#map-9

1) I Guess we can use it somehow. But what is the id of this style?

2) And do you know other styles which are more similar to the google maps streets style?

Thank You

Comment: The question you linked to already has the answer: that's the "streets" style, listed at https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapbox tiles and Leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166172/mapbox-tiles-and-leafletjs)